# Does Google Closure have support for accordion?

Tags: javascript, google-closure-library

I like the left menu style on this page:

https://developers.google.com/closure/utilities/docs/linter_howto.

If you click on the left arrow, it will drop down the folder.

Is this code included in the Google Closure library for the menu? I tried searching for it but couldn't find anything.

Comment: That's actually a tree.

Comment: Thank you, is there existing code I can get from google?

Answer (score 1):

In the closure library under closure/goog/demos there is a file index.html. Under trees there is a tree control. You might want to fiddle with the css to make it look nicer but that's basically the code.

Comment: i noticed on that closure demo on th elink your http://closure-library.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/closure/goog/demos/, that you can't use the tab key with keyboard on folder links.  But on my link up to, you can. Any thoughts>

Comment: The `goog.ui.tree.TreeControl` seems to behave like any other tree control. Navigate the tree using the arrow keys. Tab will put the focus on the next control not the the next item in the tree. This is normal behavior. If you open bookmarks in Firefox or chrome the tree control can be navigated using the arrow keys but tab will go to the next control. I'm not sure you would want to change expected behavior of a known control. I imagine it would be hard to implement because the control will loose focus on tab.

Answer (score 0):

Did you look Zippy (goog.ui.Zippy)

http://closure-library.googlecode.com/git/closure/goog/demos/zippy.html